# A proof about generalized eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, generalized-eigenvector

I'm considering the following model.
Given $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $i\in \{1,2,\ldots,N\}$, where $n\leq N$.
$X=[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N]$ and a full-rank $W\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ 
$P=[p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_d]$, where $d<n$ and $p_i$ is the generalized eigenvector vector corresponding to the $i$-th smallest eigenvalues of the following problem
$$XWX^Tp=\lambda XX^Tp.$$
I want to show that $$x_i=P(P^TP)^{-1}P^Tx_i,\forall\ i\in{1,2,\ldots,N}.$$
I don't know how to start the proof.
 Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: At first, I thought it may be the case that we have to prove that $P(P^TP)^{-1}P^T ~=~ I_d$ by showing $P$ is semi-orthogonal matrix, and to do that, we have to show that generalized eigenvector $p_k, ~ \forall k\in [d]$ is orthonormal. But since you've mentioned that $d < n$, then $P$ may only be left-invertible, and hence in your case this principle may not be applied. However, I suggest you to seek on some other similar proofs, including elaboration on left/right-invertibility of the matrices, composed of the eigenvectors of ordered spectrum.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the case that $P(P^TP)^{-1}P^T=I_n$ will never happen since $P(P^TP)^{-1}P^T$ is of dimension $n \times n$ and rank at most $d$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. If $W=I_N$ and $\lambda=1$, the equation $XWX^Tp=\lambda XX^Tp$ is always satisfied regardless of the values of $X$ and $p$. Now, if $n>d=1$, take any $p\ne0$. Then $p(p^Tp)^{-1}p^T$ is singular. Hence there exists some vector $x$ such that $x\ne p(p^Tp)^{-1}p^Tx$. Duplicate $x$ to form a matrix $X$. Now we get a counterexample.